# Searching Word 2010 document for field does not return existing bookmark field

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks

I have created a bookmark in a document by selecting the word 'foo' and inserting a bookmark with name 'bar'.

Still, when I search for fields with the name bar (using the syntax `^dbar`), no results are returned and it is not highlighted in the navigation sidebar. How do I perform a search that shows me where I've used the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say how you entered the reference. If you entered the reference using `{bar}`, `^dbar` should find it. If you entered it using `{ bar }`, `^dbar` would not find it. `^d bar` or `^d^wbar` would find it. If you entered it using `{ REF bar }`, you would need something more like `^d^wref bar`.

Comment: I've tried searching for them all. Is there anyway I can actually see the markup for the inserted bookmark?

Comment: You won't find the bookmarks themselves using that technique - better to use word's settings to make the bookmarks visible. For the ref fields that point to the bookmarks, the main "reveal codes" thing is to use alt-f9. Beyond that, I'd say you need to save the document as (say) single-file XML format, and inspect that.

Comment: So, using Alt+F9 I revealed the actual bookmark code which was `{ REF bar }`, so I used your last expression but removed the last ^w before bar and voilá, I found them all. Thanks!